# Impressão em PHP

Tags: php, impressão

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento de estoque para empresa e o cliente precisa que o sistema imprima as etiquetas em uma impressora especial para etiquetas (Datamax I-4210) os produtos cadastrados.

O sistema é web e fica em um servidor na própria empresa e está conectado em rede com a impressora.

Ontem passei o dia todo pesquisando soluções mas não obtive sucesso. Na verdade sei que é possível enviar comandos para impressoras por *socket*, só que é minha primeira experiência com tal funcionalidade e realmente estou bem perdido. Não tenho problema em enviar o *sockets* e até o envio de comandos, o problema é conseguir se conectar a impressora para enviar os comandos.

O problema em si é encontrar o IP e a porta da impressora para eu enviar os *sockets* com os comandos. Na empresa meu cliente já usa um programa desktop chamado BarOne e ele consegue imprimir as etiquetas. Provavelmente por ser um software desktop ele consegue manipular por rede a impressora e obter os dados que ele precisa para de alguma forma enviar os comandos. O mesmo não pode ser usado por mim uma vez que o sistema é em PHP e eu não posso obter esses dados da impressora.

Comment: Mas se você consegue enviar *sockets* você deve estar conectado. É difícil você ver qual endereço e porta a impressora está conectada e colocá-los no código?

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu. Eu na verdade não enviei sockets, eu disse que envia-los não seria o problema SE eu tivesse o IP e porta da impressora. O problema em si é esse. Saber o IP e porta e consegui se conectar além de saber se é uma conexão UDP ou TCP...

Comment: E porque você não pode olhar em que IP e porta a impressa está? O pessoal fica trocando toda hora? Se fica, tem algum motivo para isto?

Comment: Então como havia dito acima, ontem passei o dia procurando soluções e em relação ao IP aproveitei e perguntei junto, eu não obtive sucesso em conseguir encontrar o IP e porta da impressora

Comment: O seu problema não é fazer o código PHP para usar a impressora? É que você não sabe olhar no servidor onde ela está conectada? Aí o problema não é de programação.

Comment: Me diz uma coisa o servidor é windows? Por que se for você poderia usar `COM`, se for `linux` um `exec();` ajudaria.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive de resolver um cenário proximo a este.
Se você utiliza Linux você pode mapear a impressora de rede de modo que ela fique disponivel através do cups com o comando lp.
A partir disso é possivel chamar no php o comando lp com uma função do tipo [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php).

A solução que adotei quando tive que resolver este problema foi gerar o código de barra em PPLA e salvar em um arquivo temporário. Feito isto bastava enviar o comando lp para o CUPS e ele se virava em capturar o arquivo e imprimir.

Algumas considerações importantes antes de adotar esta solução:

1. A impressora deve ser mapeável pelo Linux. Para sanar o problema mapeamos a impressora através do mac-address do computador em que ela estava conectada;
2. É possivel enviar qualquer coisa para impressão desde que se tenha o driver correto instalado. No meu caso não tinhamos driver então como paliativo mapeamos com um driver de plain text do CUPS e passamos a enviar um arquivo PPLA para impressão.