# Como realizar impressões entre um servidor Web e uma impressora local?

Tags: php, javascript, impressão

Boa Tarde tenho a necessidade de efetuar a impressão de um recibo não fiscal direto de um sistema web. (Impressora MP 20 MI X Servidor LocaWeb X cliente Windows 10 X Sistema PHP)

A questão é que como são várias unidades utilizando o mesmo banco de dados não posso utilizar servidor local.

Existe algum meio se conectar a impressora LPT1 ou usb ou até mesmo executar um arquivo .bat para disparar essa impressão nas máquinas locais?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago, você está utilizando linguagem Web, obviamente instalada em um servidor. É claro que, se você tivesse acesso físico ao servidor, você ligaria a sua impressora através de uma rede local e funcionaria normalmente, pois a linguagem PHP está instalada dentro do servidor.

Já que com relação a questão do banco de dados está conectado a várias unidades e você não poder instalar esse sistema local, é de fato necessário que você faça o seguinte:

1. Fazer uma conexão através de uma VPN com a impressora conectada em rede em algum computador desktop. Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049591/how-can-i-make-a-website-connect-directly-to-a-printer-so-that-it-can-print-out

ou (
 2. Se você utiliza Linux você pode mapear a impressora de rede de modo que ela fique disponível através do cups com o comando lp.
A partir disso é possível chamar no php o comando lp com uma função do tipo shell_exec().

A solução que adotei quando tive que resolver este problema foi gerar o código de barra em PPLA e salvar em um arquivo temporário. Feito isto bastava enviar o comando lp para o CUPS e ele se virava em capturar o arquivo e imprimir.

Algumas considerações importantes antes de adotar esta solução:

A impressora deve ser mapeável pelo Linux. Para sanar o problema mapeamos a impressora através do mac-address do computador em que ela estava conectada;
É possível enviar qualquer coisa para impressão desde que se tenha o driver correto instalado. No meu caso não tínhamos driver então como paliativo mapeamos com um driver de plain text do CUPS e passamos a enviar um arquivo PPLA para impressão. ) Fonte: [Impressão em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49707/impress%C3%A3o-em-php?rq=1)

Comment: O complicado é que nem sempre é a mesma impressora..
eu havia adotado um comando via exec direto na porta por generic text mas não consigo executar o mesmo comando agora que o sistema esta online...ou estou fazendo isso de forma errada... mas vou tentar dessa forma obrigado!

Comment: Já que não é a mesma impressora, você deve escrever em algum arquivo ou banco de dados as portas de cada impressora, dá um nome pra elas e fazer um botão 'combobox' par que o usuário possa escolher a impressora que deseja realizar a impressão, assim você permite que o usuário escolha, semelhante como fazemos normalmente com linguagens desktop, mas lembre que a ou as impressoras, precisam estar mapeadas e com ip local fixo para evitar problemas com DNS.